# Plotly county choropleth map

Tags: python, visualization, plotly

I was able to use county choropleth map created using create_choropleth function ( https://plot.ly/python/county-choropleth/ ).

When we hover over county it shows data using County, State, FIPS and Value tag.
Is there a way to customized this text so that it displays only county name and another tag attribute with a value. For example :- desired output - County : Westmoreland , Attribute1 : Value1 , Attribute 2 ;Value2.

Example:- 
                 Original County Choloropleth Map Hover Text
                  County: xx
                  State:xx
                  FIPS:xx
                  Value:xx

```
             Expected County Choloropleth Map Hover Text
             County : xx
             Attribute 1 :Value 1
             Attribute 2 :Value 2
```

Comment: Please add a [MCVE] to your question, otherwise it is hard to give an answer which is not based on guessing and assumptions.

Comment: Example :- Original County Choloropleth Map Hover Text
                  County: xx
                  State:xx
                  FIPS:xx
                  Value:xx
       
                 Expected County Choloropleth Map Hover Text
                 County : xx
                 Attribute 1 :Value 1
                 Attribute 2 :Value 2